# What is the difference between the follow ways to do word count in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Apache Flink provides many operations for DataSet. It is a little hard to understand how the data processed in the cluster. For example WordCount has different implements. What is the difference?

It would be very helpful if there are some documents to explain what is the data flow for these implements in the cluster.

```
    // get input data
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
            "To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
            "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer",
            "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",
            "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,"
            );
    // WordCount 1
    text.flatMap(new LineSplitter()).groupBy(0).sum(1).print();

    // WordCount 2
    text.flatMap(new LineSplitter()).groupBy(0).aggregate(Aggregations.SUM, 1).print();

    // WordCount 3
    text.flatMap(new LineSplitter()).groupBy(0)
            .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<String, Integer> t1, Tuple2<String, Integer> t2) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(t1.f0, t1.f1+t2.f1);
            }
        }).print();

    // WordCount 4
    text.flatMap(new LineSplitter()).groupBy(0)
            .reduceGroup(new GroupReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void reduce(Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collector) throws Exception {
                    int prefixSum = 0;
                    String key = null;
                    for (Tuple2<String, Integer> t : iterable) {
                        prefixSum += t.f1;
                        key = t.f0;
                    }
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(key, prefixSum));
            }
        }).print();

    // WordCount 5
    text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
        .reduceGroup(new GroupReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void reduce(Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collector) throws Exception {
                HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                for(Tuple2<String, Integer> t : iterable){
                    if(map.containsKey(t.f0)){
                        map.replace(t.f0, map.get(t.f0)+t.f1);
                    } else {
                        map.put(t.f0, t.f1);
                    }
                }
                for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : map.entrySet()){
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()));
                }
            }
        }).print();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for WordCount 5, all programs are executed very similar to a regular MapReduce WordCount program (hash-based shuffle and sort-based grouping).

- WordCount 1 is syntactic sugar for WordCount 2
- WordCount 2 is internally executed with a `GroupReduceFunction` that is similar to the one in WordCount 4. The only difference is that the internal `GroupReduceFunction` implements the `Combinable` interface in order to support partial aggregations.
- WordCount 3 uses a `ReduceFunction` which is executed similar to a `GroupReduceFunction`. However, due to the different interface a `ReduceFunction` is always combinable (without requiring a separate `combine` method).
- WordCount 4 is executed just like a regular MapReduce program: shuffle with hash-partitioning and sort-based grouping. Because the `GroupReduceFunction` does not implement the `Combinable` interface, this program is executed without local pre-aggregation and hence less efficient than the previous three programs.
- WordCount 5 is very inefficient and should not be used because the `GroupReduceFunction` cannot be executed in parallel. Since there is no `groupBy()` call, all data is sent to the same Reducer and handled as one large group. First, this will be slow because it is executed in a single thread and restricted by the network throughput of a single machine. Second, this program can easily fail if the number of distinct keys grows too large because the grouping is done using an in-memory `HashMap`.